# Headers not visible in ModelAdmin get_form()

Tags: python, django, django-admin

My model is such that each website has an associated email address. An administrator would select a set of websites on the website list view and use an admin action to pass the email addresses of the selected websites to recipient field of a new email_message object. From here, the administrator should be able to customize an email that is sent to each of those email addresses.

The problem is that I can't pass headers to the get_form() method in the new email_message view. When I run the code, the print function that you see included here prints `<QueryDict: {}>`.

How can I pass header data from an admin action to another model's get_form method?

**admin.py:**

```
def email_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    response = HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/websites/email_message/add/')
    response['queryset'] = queryset
    return response

class WebsiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [email_selected]

class Email_messageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj, **kwargs):
        print(request.GET)
        form = super(Email_messageAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        return form
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: What type is the recipient field, is it just a char field? You're setting a header but printing the GET parameters

Comment: The recipient field is a list of email_addresses objects. At this point it doesn't matter what type it sends because I just want it to send SOMETHING. Right now, the header information that I'm passing to the HttpResponseRedirect method is getting erased before reaching get_form(). Eventually, it will send a list of email_address objects, which are the addresses that will act as recipients to my email_message object. For now, even passing a string through the header would be enough to get me going in the right direction.

Comment: I have found the problem but not the solution. The problem is that I'm calling get_form() from HttpResponseRedirect(). This would not be a problem for HttpResponse() but since I am redirecting it, headers cannot be kept. I haven't found any solution for this. Only work-arounds.